# Refashion a jQuery each() loop to Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each

I'm trying to convert a jQuery `each()` function to vanilla javascript, and I'm  almost there, but i can't seem to work out a way of storing multiple instances of the same element in a variable to add to my array which is then iterated over with the `for loop` which replaces `each()`.

The problem I have is getting the elements inside the 'arr' array to represent each instance of the element.

** Note i've commented out the original simplified `each()` loop, but if you un-comment this you'll see what is meant to happen.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/aqdWzp

JS

```
// // ----------  EACH LOOP ON TEXT ELEMENTS

// $('div, h1').each(function(){
//         var myElement = this;
//         myElement.style.cssText = "background: red; transition: 1s"
// });


// // ----------  VANILLA JS

var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];

var arr = [div, h1];

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

  var myElement = arr[i];
  arr[i] = this;

  myElement.style.cssText = "background: red; transition: 1s"

}
```

CSS

```
body {display: flex; margin: 20px; padding: 0; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; justify-content: center;}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<h1>a heading</h1>
```

Comment: What is the use of that line? `arr[i] = this;`

Comment: And why the `[0]` in `document.getElementsByTagName("...")[0]`?

Comment: You might be looking for `document.querySelectorAll("div, h1")`

Comment: @LioraHaydont I need to reference 'this' because the elements are going to be self-triggering for a scrollMagic function.

Comment: @Andreas the [0] was to stop it throwing an error as I explained the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you're creating a 2d array of your elements, not a single flattened array which contains them all (which would be more analogous to the collection held in a jQuery object).

To fix this you can use `querySelectorAll()` to get the elements, then a simple `forEach()` loop to iterate over them. Also note that it's better practice to apply CSS classes to elements instead of direct styling, and the `transition` rule needs to be placed on the element before the setting to be transitioned is changed. Try this:

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('div, h1'), function(element) {
  element.classList.add('red');
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  transition: all 1s;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.red { 
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<h1>a heading</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

Here you are:

```js
// ----------  Original Code

// $('div, h1').each(function(){
//         var myElement = this;
//         myElement.style.cssText = "background: red; transition: 1s"
// });

// ----------  VANILLA JS

const elems = document.querySelectorAll('dev,h1')

elems.forEach(e => {
  e.style.cssText = "background: red; transition: 1s"
})
```

### Notes:

- You don't need to use `this` in vanilla js. The element references in the array are the elements itself!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get a static [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), and than iterate it with [`NodeList.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach):

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll("div, h1");

els.forEach(function(el) {
  el.style.cssText = "background: red; transition: 1s"
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<h1>a heading</h1>
```